# 25x25 slitherlink puzzle

Tags: grid-deduction, slitherlink

### Basic rules

Form a loop using the dots (so, by joining orthogonally adjacent dots) such that a number N is surrounded by exactly N segments of the loop. Here's a tutorial puzzle and its unique solution:

[image]

> [image]

### Actual puzzle

Here's an easy-ish [slitherlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slitherlink). A solution has been checked, and it should be fine, but sorry if there's any ambiguity that got past the checks.

[image]

or [play online](http://pzv.jp/p.html?slither/25/25/zl13731822630723621c11722723632711711c11611821631831622czk11731521711722623d11621611712620622c12612721531611611bzk00711622712811721d00612721722633723b21512733711712701azk10701601731712711d21611513622811501c22722702611601712czk20712822601712522d11722612811712612c21822732722632722dzk11712822621811802b10611622621712713b21833803602823612dzj). Have fun!

Comment: Wow. That's impressive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved it! It was a lot of fun!

> [image]

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to point out that there are actually two answers, so this Slitherlink is not solvable through pure logic:

> [image: Answer 1]

and:

> [image: Answer 2]

differing in this little region:

> [image: Part solvable through logic]

To fix the problem, I think it is possible to:

> Swap the bottom 1 and 2 around